# Trying to write list items to text file but the file ends up blank

Tags: c#, arraylist, filestream

I have a class `TestLogEntry` whose `ToString()` method I've overridden as follows:

```
   class TestLogEntry
    {
        public int counter;
        public string filename;
        public long id;
        public int featureCount_existing;
        public string fromPath;
        public int featureCount;
        public bool isCheckedOut;
        public bool modifiedByThisUser;
        public bool canUpdate;

        public string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8}", counter, filename, id, featureCount_existing, fromPath, featureCount, isCheckedOut, modifiedByThisUser, canUpdate);
        }
    }
```

I have a `List<TestLogEntry>` instance `testLog` that I'm trying to read into a text file:

```
    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(@"C:\Logs\TestLog\testLog.csv",FileMode.Create))
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        testLog.ForEach(r => sw.WriteLine(r.ToString()));
    }
```

`testLog` clearly has data in it when I examine it at a breakpoint at the `ForEach` statement, but after this completes, the file is blank.  How do I write the list contents to the file?

Comment: `File.WriteAllLines(path, testLog.Select(t => t.ToString()))`?

Comment: Have you tried sw.Close()?

Comment: that `StreamWriter` should also be in a `using` statement so it gets closed and disposed.

Comment: But it's much easier and safer to just use the `File` class wrappers, like `WriteAllLines`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to close StreamWriter at the end.
Can you try adding sw.Close(); after foreach statement.

Answer (score 1):

Add `sw.Close()`

```cs
    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(@"C:\Logs\TestLog\testLog.csv",FileMode.Create))
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        testLog.ForEach(r => sw.WriteLine(r.ToString()));
        sw.Close();
    }
```